# How to play youtube video in QTMovieView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, youtube, qtkit

I'm developing a cocoa application. I have to play a youtube video.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dElLBPL_h1Q

I'm using QTKit for playing video. Code is as follow:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dElLBPL_h1Q"];
QTMovie *movie = [QTMovie movieWithURL:fileURL error:&error];
[movieView setMovie:movie];
[movieView.movie play];
```

Where, movieView is an instance of QTMovieView.

Please help.

Comment: Check out if your video is in one of these formats : AVI, AVR, DV, M-JPEG, MPEG-1, MPEG-2, MPEG-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LBYouTubeView](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView) to play YouTube videos with choice of streaming with `high-quality` and `standard quality` .

`LBYouTubeView` contains is `LBYouTubePlayerViewController` and its just a small view that is able to display `YouTube` videos in a `MPMoviePlayerController`. You even have the choice between `high-quality` and `standard quality` `stream`.

**EDIT** : Its easy to use.